# Change page state with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm developing a page having a grid of icons (think iOS home screen) and I want to have a  button that set the whole page in a delete state, that means, any icon I click instead of doing what's he's supposed to do (open a page in a new tab), get's deleted. I'm not sure how to go on with this,

I've tried this: when the state change button is pressed, all "href"s of the icons get changed to a delete page with the id of the entity (something like /delete?key=abcd123). By the way, i'm using google's app engine, with java, and the datastore.

I need some guidelines, how should I do this ?

Comment: What's the problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to create a jquery script to change the onclick attribute.
Iterate through all the classes you want to change

```
$(".class_to_change").attr({onclick: "delete_function()"});
```